# Is UnityPlayer.dll third party licences files missing things?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am distributing UnityPlayer.dll alongside the Unity license and its third party license attributions.
I found what I think are the third party attributions in the legal.txt files distributed with the unity editor install.

According to Synopsys Black Duck, UnityPlayer.dll also contains libflac and mbed_tls.

Are these false positives from Black Duck? Do I have the wrong license file?